# Why is my session canceled after data flushing?

Tags: php

within a project I had to create some asynchronous calls and a monitoring system through a progress bar.

Asynchronous calls are launched and during their execution they update a session containing a percentage value. A second asynchronous call takes care of reading the percentage value and updating a progress bar.

The script that takes care of reading is launched by an EventSource, but I encountered difficulties when I insert the flush function necessary to send the information to javascript.

In fact, if I remove flush() the information is not sent to javascript, but I can read correctly in the session and the result of session_status() is 2. In case I insert flush() the data is sent correctly, but I cannot read in session and session_status() returns 1.

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

require_once '../../../../config/system.config.php'; // Define some constants
require_once '../../../../config/header.config.php'; // Include Classes


while (true) {

    ob_start();

    $_Response -> executeFunction('AsyncOperation', 'getActiveTasks', NULL);

    echo "data: ".$_Response -> serialize()."\n\n";

    ob_end_flush();
    flush();

    sleep(10);

}
```

Why? Help me, because I no longer know which way to go.

Comment: What is `executeFunction()`?

Comment: Sorry, executeFunction get data in $_SESSION you can read that like:

start_session();
session_commit();
return $_SESSION['mySession']; and serialize is json_encode()

Comment: The feeling I had was that after the flush, the session could no longer be started. In fact, if I remove the while and let the script be opened and closed I solve the problem.

What I'd like is to keep the script listening without having to make a call every N seconds.